# Template type deduction when converting from one type to another

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I want to write a simple wrapper for the static_cast operator.
My first attempt on the same is as shown below:

```
template <typename ForConvert, typename ToConvert>
ToConvert Convert(ForConvert val)
{
    return static_cast<ToConvert> (val);
}
```

And now I can use it like

```
auto x = 25;
auto y = Convert<int, float>(x);
```

Is there a way for the **ForConvert** part to be implicit? I want to be able to use the convert function like this :

```
auto x = 25;
auto y = Convert<float>(x);
```

Is there a way/technique(when defining the template function) so that compiler is able to deduce the type of x so that I shouldn't have to specify it explicitly? In a way I think I am asking how static_cast itself is implemented :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of the template parameters.

```
template <typename ToConvert, typename ForConvert>
ToConvert Convert(ForConvert val)
{
    return static_cast<ToConvert> (val);
}
```

Now if you write

```
Convert<float>(x)
```

the `float` is used to fill in the first template parameter, `ToConvert`, and `ForConvert` is deduced from `x` since it's not given explicitly.